# Is there a way to get the CMOS time out of the BIOS in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, bios

I'm currently putting together a script that collects information about a PC when I'm remotely accessing it and I'd like to also get information about the hardware status of the machine, specifically the CMOS time. Is there any way to do this using PowerShell?

For context, thus far I've always collected most of this data manually, however now I'd like to automate it. I've found very little online and I'm beginning to wonder if it is even possible. Does anyone have any experience with collecting BIOS data using PowerShell in Windows?

Comment: You can get a lot of BIOS details using the [Win32_BIOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-bios) WMI class, but I don't think it gets the time.  What's wrong with getting the time using [Get-Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-6) for example?

Comment: @boxdog well, I'd like to find out wether or not the BIOS battery has run out recently and therefore reset the time to a wrong date after bootup - thank you nevertheless, I dont think there is any way of getting this data in Windows directly.